# Renaming the files with prepending parent directory name

Tags: bash, rename

Need to mass rename files that prepending their parent directory name to them without using `rename` command.

e.g.

```
/tmp/2017-09-22/cyber.gz
/tmp/2017-09-23/cyber.gz
/tmp/2017-09-24/cyber.tar
```

Also renamed files has to be copy in `/tmp/archive` without impacting above original files.

Looks like below

```
/tmp/archive/2017-09-22_cyber.gz
/tmp/archive/2017-09-23_cyber.gz
/tmp/archive/2017-09-24_cyber.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

If not using `rename` here is how you can do with [`Shell (Bash, ksh, ksh93, mksh, zsh) Pattern substitution expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
find * -path "archive" -prune -o -type f -exec \
    bash -c 'echo "$1" "archive/${1/\//_}"' find_bash '{}' \;
```

- `-path "archive" -prune` is excluding `archive` directory itself.
- `${1/\//_}` is replacing Slash `/` with Underscore `_`. The `1` is point to the `find_bash` first parameter which is file path passing by `{}`.

(Replace `echo` with `cp` to copy or `mv` to move the files)

Directory structure:

```
.
├── 2017-09-22
│   └── cyber.gz
├── 2017-09-23
│   └── cyber.gz
├── 2017-09-24
│   └── cyber.tar
└── archive
```

After executing the command:

```
.
├── 2017-09-22
│   └── cyber.gz
├── 2017-09-23
│   └── cyber.gz
├── 2017-09-24
│   └── cyber.tar
└── archive
    ├── 2017-09-22_cyber.gz
    ├── 2017-09-23_cyber.gz
    └── 2017-09-24_cyber.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a short shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

archive='/tmp/archive'

mkdir -p "$archive"

for name in /tmp/????-??-??/*; do
    dirdate=${name%/*}         # dirdate=$(dirname "$name")
    dirdate=${dirdate##*/}     # dirdate=$(basename "$dirdate")

    newname="$archive/${dirdate}_${name##*/}"

    if [ ! -e "$newname" ]; then
        echo cp "$name" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

This picks out `dirdate` as the basename of the directories that have dates as their names, and creates a new name for each file inside using this.

If the new name does not exist inside the `archive` directory, the file is copied there.

Remove `echo` from the above script to actually perform the copying.

For the given example, the script will perform the following operations:

```
cp /tmp/2017-09-22/cyber.gz /tmp/archive/2017-09-22_cyber.gz
cp /tmp/2017-09-23/cyber.gz /tmp/archive/2017-09-23_cyber.gz
cp /tmp/2017-09-24/cyber.tar /tmp/archive/2017-09-24_cyber.tar
```